# Placing a bid inside a bids table using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to build a bidding application. I want to a associate a textfield with the primary key of the row outputted. e.g textfield is bid_amount . when you enter the bid amount i want the bid_amount entered and the person who bidded(truckerid) and the product bidded for (luggage_id) to be stored in bids table . the outputted products to bid for are stored in another table (consignment table) Below is my model, view and controller.

Below are the errors that am getting

A Database Error Occurred

```
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'
UPDATE `bids` SET `luggage_id` = NULL, `bid_amount` = Array, `truckerid` = '84K7B7'
Filename: models/Truckeraccount_model.php
Line Number: 129
```

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: database/DB_driver.php
Line Number: 1524
```

Below is my model, view and controller.

View

```
  <h2 class="page-header">
          <i class="fa fa-legal"></i> &nbsp <font color="orange"> Loads To Bid For </font> 
      </h2>
    </div><!-- /.col -->
  </div>

 <?php

                foreach ($h->result() as $row)  
   {
   ?>         

  <div class="row invoice-info">
   <div class="col-sm-1 invoice-col">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 invoice-col">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>/res/images/goods/1.png">              
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 invoice-col">
    <address>
    Description: <?php echo $row->description;?><br>
    Location Address: <?php echo $row->l_area;?><br>
    Destination Address: <?php echo $row->d_area;?><br>
    Date: <?php echo $row->dom;?><br>
    Time: <?php echo $row->tom;?>
    </address>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 invoice-col">
    <address>
    </address>
    </div><!-- /.col -->
    <div class="col-sm-2 invoice-col">

        <?php echo form_open('truckeraccount_ctrl/bid'); ?>
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="truckerid" value="<?php 
        $truckerid = $this->session->userdata('truckerid');
        echo $truckerid; ?>" required>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bid_amount[$row->luggage_id]" placeholder="Bid">
        <button type="submit" class="btn bg-orange btn-flat margin">Place Bid</button>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Controller

```
 public function bid(){


                        $this->load->model('Truckeraccount_model');
                      //  $luggage_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
                        $this->Truckeraccount_model->bid();
                        redirect('truckeraccount_ctrl');

   }
```

Model

```
function bid(){  

                        $data = array(

                        'luggage_id' => $this->input->post('luggage_id'),
                        'bid_amount' => $this->input->post('bid_amount'),
                        'truckerid' => $this->input->post('truckerid')
                        );
                        //$this->db->where('luggage_id', $luggage_id);
                        $query=$this->db->update('bids', $data);
                        return $query;  

    }
```

Comment: And what is your problem? We are not a coding service.

Comment: Its failing to input bid_amount in bids table. I wonder where am going wrong

Comment: There will be an error or similar, please edit your question and add these details.

Comment: Have edited to include errors. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in this **bid_amount[$row->luggage_id]** section in the form. You can not put a third bracket in field name, if it is written it will be treated as an array.